# Python packages imported in editable mode can't be resolved by pylance in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have several Python packages developed locally, which I often use in VSCode projects. For these projects, I create a new virtualenv and install these packages with `pip install -e ../path/to/package`. This succeeds, and I can use these packages in the project. However, VSCode underlines the package's import line in yellow, with this error:

> Import "mypackage" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

Again, `mypackage` works fine in the project, but VSCode reports that error, and I lose all autocomplete and type hint features when calling `mypackage` in the project.

I ensured that the right Python interpreter is selected (the one from the project's virtualenv), but the error persists. The error and Pylance docs do not offer any other possible solutions.

VSCode version: 1.78.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when you choose the correct interpreter, Pylance should take effect immediately. You can try adding `"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["path/to/your/package"]` to your `settings.json`.

You can also try clicking on the install prompt in vscode to see which environment it will install the package in. I still believe that the problem was caused by incorrect selection of the interpreter.

Comment: My case could be solved in 2 different ways: If I used the installation method with "editable_mode" with "strict" suggested by AlexOver. Or if I followed your suggestion, which seems to bypass an improper installation of the local package.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem, found a solution in Pylance's ticket [#3473](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3473)

Try installing with `pip install -e . --config-settings editable_mode=strict`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34840046)

Comment: if im not wrong that means it wont see new folders you create in your package